# Can't access Windows 10 after dual boot

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, boot-repair

I have a HP Pavilion laptop and I was running Windows 10 on it. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it in a separate partition for dual boot using a LiveUSB and everything went well the first time.

When I had to restart after installing Ubuntu, I could not get the GRUB menu options to boot into either Windows/Ubuntu. I got the try Ubuntu and install Ubuntu options again. So I went ahead with install Ubuntu and went ahead with the installation. After that, I got a message to reboot the PC after removing the installation media. So I did that and did the reboot.

After the reboot, I could only access Ubuntu from the GRUB menu. I can't see any option to load Windows from GRUB.

I searched a lot in the forums and tried some stuff like `boot repair` and adding lines to the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and `sudo update-grub` but nothing seems to work.

Here is my [Boot repair URL](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23307695/)

I logged into Ubuntu and tried the `boot repair` but it failed and the message popped up that I should use the boot repair from a Live USB or CD. So I created a boot repair live USB and performed the `recommended repair`. This is what I got :

```
GPT detected. Please create a BIOD-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as GParted. Then try again. Alternatively, you can retry after activating the [Separate /boot/efi partition:] option.
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8uPt.png) is an image of my partitions from GParted.

Thanks for the help!